# If I have two listboxes in my webpage, but i need one listbox to be Multiselect the other should be general listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ multi select plugin.By default, this plugin automatically turn normal html select box to multi select box,  Is there any way i can use this multi select plugin along with general html select box on same page?

Bundle of Thanks in Advance.
Jay

Comment: Whats the problem if you add select element , are you tried adding ?

Comment: please check the documentation for single select here http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#single

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the option `multiple` to false.
Or don't call `$('select').multiselect`

Add a class

```
<select class="multiple-select"></select>
```

then change your selector to: `$('.multiple-select').multiselect` and leave the regular select without the class.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6cvqm/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joe! Works Perfect, Thumbs UP !!

Comment: Hi @Jay, be sure to either accept an answer and vote for helpful posts. It's the oil that keeps stackoverflow turning.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize, do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#mymulti").multiselect();
});

<select id="mymulti" name="example" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
   <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

This:

```
$("#mymulti").multiselect();
```

will only work on the select with id = mymulti

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with some id $("select#multiple"), so that all select box will not rendered with that plug-in.

```
$("select#multiple").multiselect({
   header: "Select an option",
   noneSelectedText: "Select an Option",
   selectedList: 1
});
```